# <HTCData><Facebook> auto sync after changing ROM

Tags: contacts, cyanogenmod, sync, facebook

I had stock rom for my HTC Wildfire S with HTC Sense and facebook. I had joined contacts - Google account and Facebook friends.
Now I flashed to Cyanogen mod 7 and they are not synchronised. But I noticed, that every contact (which was synced before) has Note with hash like: `<HTCData><Facebook>id:xxxxxxx/friendof:xxxxxxx</Facebook></HTCData>`

Is there any way to put it back together automatically?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

CyanogenMod does not use the `<HTCData><Facebook>id:xxxxxxx/friendof:xxxxxxx</Facebook></HTCData>` tag as HTC Sense does, so this can just be deleted.

The Facebook contact sync is setup inside the **Facebook for Android** app (Settings -> Sync friends with Contacts). This should automatically add Facebook pictures and contact info to Contacts.

However, I have experienced that the contact pictures do not always sync after a reboot, until I have opened the Facebook app and scrolled through my friend list (then the images are loaded). Therefore, I installed another app called SyncMyPix for the picture synchronization.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try SyncMyPix app, pictures are the main reason, why I want to synchronized it.

But it's strange, when I synchronize my contacts with facebook contacts manualy, there's new Note, the same like the older.. So, I think it's possible some reversal sync...

Comment: @ajgarn is right, only htc contacts app is capable of using the <HTCData> for linking accounts (it actually does not synchronize them, only "link")